# When I run flutter doctor command on mac its showing below, while I already install Android Studio, and I can run ios build from Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

When I run flutter doctor command on mac its showing below, while I already install Android Studio, and I can run ios build from Android Studio.

```
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.207], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Comment: do you set up path variables correctly..?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use cmd or powershell or something, you have to check licenses. it is free
but need cmd

search-cmd-enter. Dos screen will appear

you can command flutter doctor --android-licenses. try it. I hope solved

Comment: There's not cmd in MacOS but there's terminal. Typing same in macos terminal should help as you point.